# Как сократить часть с if-ами?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
deck = Deck(deck_size)
for _ in range(commands):
    cmd = input().strip().split()

    if cmd[0] == CMD_POP_FRONT:
        try:
            print(deck.pop_front())
        except ValueError:
            print('error')
        continue

    if cmd[0] == CMD_POP_BACK:
        try:
            print(deck.pop_back())
        except ValueError:
            print('error')
        continue

    if cmd[0] == CMD_PUSH_FRONT:
        try:
            deck.push_front(int(cmd[1]))
        except OverflowError:
            print('error')
        continue

    if cmd[0] == CMD_PUSH_BACK:
        try:
            deck.push_back(int(cmd[1]))
        except OverflowError:
            print('error')
```

Comment: `continue` точно нужен? Мб `try:` / `except` вынести на весь цикл, а не на каждую команду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
deck = Deck(deck_size)
for _ in range(commands):
    cmd = input().strip().split()
    try:
        if   cmd[0] == CMD_POP_FRONT:
            print(deck.pop_front())
        elif cmd[0] == CMD_POP_BACK:
            print(deck.pop_back())
        elif cmd[0] == CMD_PUSH_FRONT:
            deck.push_front(int(cmd[1]))
        elif cmd[0] == CMD_PUSH_BACK:
            deck.push_back(int(cmd[1]))
    except (ValueError, OverflowError):
        print('error')
```

Или сделать что-то вроде map'ы функций и вызывать по ней.

```
cmd_func = {CMD_POP_FRONT : lambda *x: print(deck.pop_front())   ,
            CMD_POP_BACK  : lambda *x: print(deck.pop_back())    ,
            CMD_PUSH_FRONT: lambda *x: deck.push_front(int(x[0])),
            CMD_PUSH_BACK : lambda *x: deck.push_back(int(x[0]))
           }

deck = Deck(deck_size)
for _ in range(commands):
    cmd = input().strip().split()
    try:
        cmd_func[cmd[0]](*cmd[1:])
    except (ValueError, OverflowError):
        print('error')
```

Comment: Или можно поставить 3.10 и забабахать match/case https://towardsdatascience.com/switch-case-statements-are-coming-to-python-d0caf7b2bfd3 (рандомная новость на тему с примером кода)